# Why does $('selector').text(""); remove element nodes in addition to text nodes?

Tags: jquery, dom

I tried to use `$('selector').text("")` to remove a text node from a parent element, and it removed all of the parent's element nodes, too.  The text node in question was "floating" between two element nodes, inside the parent element, like the "or" in this example (HTML was generated by a vendor's system):

```
<div class="controls" form-inline text-center>
  <input type="hidden" name="add_record" value="1">
    or
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info submit" data-id="1" value="Submit & Clear">
  <a name="Submit & Clear" title="'Submit & Clear' submits the current transaction and clears all fields after submission." style="cursor: default"></a>
</div>
```

I did find the correct way to delete only this text node, using `$('selector').contents()` and then filtering for `nodeType === 3`, but I would like to understand why my original script, using text() deleted the element nodes.

I've set up a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c63f5m6v/5/) with a script that correctly removes only the text node, and a script that uses `text()` and removes all child nodes.  I'd appreciate some help to correct my misunderstanding of what I expected `text()` would do here. Thank you.

Comment: because... that's what it does. http://api.jquery.com/text

Comment: Wrap the text you eventually want to change with a tag. In this case, I would suggest `<span>`. Then give it an `id` od `class` to target it.

Comment: My understanding from the documentation is that it would remove the text nodes from all child elements, but not the elements themselves, and when I view the markup in Chrome Developer Tools, I only see the parent div, and no child elements at all.  Also the jQuery docs say "The .text() method cannot be used on form inputs or scripts.", which seems to be a reference to needing to use val() vs. text(), but doesn't help me understand why, at least for the markup in the example in my question, text("") appears to completely remove the <input> elements.  I'm sure I'm missing something here, though?

Comment: It replaces **THE CONTENT** of the targetted element. `.html()` interpret the string passed as argument as HTML code while `.text()` interpret it as text. Both case: all content is replaced.

Comment: So, using `.text()`, a string like `<span>or</span>` would become `&lt;span&gt;or&lt;/span&gt;`. And using `.html()` the tags are preserved. In both cases: all content ot the targetted element is totally replaced with the string.

Comment: Thanks, Louys.  This helps me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just how the API was designed, for performance and consistency reasons.

From [the jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text2):

> `.text( text )`
>
> **Returns:** *jQuery*
>
> **Description:** Set the content of each element in the set of matched elements to the specified text.

Performance-wise, this implementation makes the most sense because it is far less work to leverage the built-in `textContent` (or `innerText`, for IE) property of HTML elements (which replace the entire content of the element with a text node as well) than to search through the list of child nodes and update any text nodes that are found.

Consistency-wise, `.text(text)` is very similar to `.html(html)`, so it makes sense that they would behave in a similar fashion: replacing the entire content of the node with text data or html data, respectively.

Comment: Thanks, gyre.  This is the behavior I saw.  I just hadn't seen anything that made me expect text() would behave similarly to html().

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you can use `.text()` in two ways, for getting the text of an element, or setting the text of an element.

For instance, to **get** the text of an element:

`<p class="element">Hello <span>this is text</span></p>`

`var text = $('.element').text();` returns `Hello this is text`

`var text = $('.element').html();` returns `Hello <span>this is text</span>`

To **set** the text of an element:

`$('.element').text('Hi there');` HTML becomes: `<p class="element">Hi there</p>`

So how setting with text() works, is that it firstly clears out everything inside the element, and replaces it with the argument you pass to `text()`.

Comment: I appreciate your help, rory.  I accepted gyre's answer because they posted a minute quicker.